# jquery.redirect issue in Firefox, works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, redirect, post-redirect-get

I have the following jQuery redirect code (using jquery.redirect.js):

**[jQuery.redirect plugin doc](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js)**

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $ = jQuery.noConflict();
            $.redirect('https://direct.tranzila.com/hatunot/', {"sum":289,"pdesc":"1 x \u05d1\u05d2\u05d3 \u05d2\u05d5\u05e3 \u05dc\u05d1 \u05e9\u05de\u05e0\u05ea \u05e4\u05e8\u05d7\u05d5\u05e0\u05d9","contact":"\u05d8\u05dc \u05d1\u05d9\u05d3\u05e7\u05d4","company":"Personal","email":"taltest@gmail.com","phone":"555555","fax":"","address":"\u05d3\u05d2\u05db\u05d3\u05d2 \u05d3\u05d2\u05db\u05d3\u05d2","city":"\u05d3\u05d2\u05db\u05d3\u05d2\u05db","remarks":"","currency":"1","myid":"","TranzilaToken":"orGzf5G2ZQ3LTNlbiepXc1l4O6ll3Rln9yQG_PLUS_17mV06u8iwZkBGz_SLASH_v97O1_SLASH_jzBXgl0LW_SLASH_jstL_SLASH_ywDjepwyuCS0YBYTkEPUtrqwJsNQrNZUQ_EQUALS_","orderid":1801,"cred_type":"1"}, 'POST')           </script>
```

Works perfectly in Chrome, and browser redirects to the above address with all the parameters, but it will not redirect with Firefox.

I created a simple test page - http://mydayshop.co.il/test.php - will work in IE/Chrome, but not in Firefox.

No errors logged in console/firebug.

What could be the case for Firefox not redirecting ?

Comment: https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `jquery.redirect.js`, `jQuery( html, attributes )` way is not working in Firefox.

I modified the code & now your problem can be fixed using modified version of `jquery.redirect.js`:

```
/* jQuery POST/GET redirect method
   v.0.1
    modified by Miguel Galante,https://github.com/mgalante
   v.0.1
   made by Nemanja Avramovic, www.avramovic.info 
   */

;(function( $ ){

    $.redirect = function( target, values, method ) {  

        method = (method && method.toUpperCase() == 'GET') ? 'GET' : 'POST';

        if (!values)
        {
            var obj = $.parse_url(target);
            target = obj.url;
            values = obj.params;
        }

        var form = $('<form>');
            form.attr('method', method);
            form.attr('action', target);

        for(var i in values)
        {
            var input = $('<input>');
                input.attr('type', 'hidden');
                input.attr('name', i);
                input.attr('value', values[i]);
                input.appendTo(form);

        }



        $('body').append(form);
    //console.log(form);
    form.submit();
    };

    $.parse_url = function(url)
    {
        if (url.indexOf('?') == -1)
            return { url: url, params: {} }

        var parts = url.split('?');
        var url = parts[0];
        var query_string = parts[1];

        var return_obj = {};
        var elems = query_string.split('&');

        var obj = {};

        for(var i in elems)
        {
            var elem = elems[i];
            var pair = elem.split('=');
            obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        return_obj.url = url;
        return_obj.params = obj;

        return return_obj;      
    }   
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: I added the comment to the console.log, and also copy/pasted the entire script you showed, but no dice. Still will not redirect with Firefox. You can see the test page http://mydayshop.co.il/test.php

Comment: Thank you my friend, it does work, my mistake. I added <body> tag and then it started working with the test file.